# Set notation equivalence of AND & OR

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Very simple,

When I am talking about sets, AND means multiplication and OR addition, am I right?

Also, I just wanted to know if the ∀ symbol indeed means for all.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I dont know what you mean by addition and multiplication when talking about sets.

Comment: If you have two sets $A$ and $B$, we have two related operators with respect to your question. The [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of $A$ and $B$ is denoted as $A \cap B$ and should be interpreted as all the elements that are both in $A$ and in $B$. The [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29) of $A$ and $B$ is denoted as $A \cup B$ and should be interpreted as all the elements that are in $A$ or in $B$, or in both $A$ and $B$. The symbol $\forall$ indeed means for all.

Comment: More or less : the set operation of "union" : $A \cup B$ is defined as follow : ($x \in A \cup B$) **iff** ($x \in A$ **or** $x \in B$); thus we can say that $\cup$ is "equivalent" to "OR" (and similarly for $\cap$ and "AND").

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** 
\begin{align}
A\cup B \mathop{:=} &\{ x \;\;\big|\;\; (x\in A) \;\;OR \;\;(x\in B)\;\;\}\\
A\cap B \mathop{:=} &\{ x \;\;\big|\;\; (x\in A) \;\;AND \;\;(x\in B)\;\;\}\\
\end{align}
and for a family of sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$
$$
x\in \bigcap_{i\in I}A_i \mbox{ if, only if } x\in A_i,\;\; \forall i\in I
$$
**Updade:** Analogies with the addition and multiplication can also come from property (under appropriate assumptions) of a probability on sets.If $A$ and $B$ are joint sets ($A\cap B=\emptyset$ ) we have a similar notion addition:$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$$.If $A$ and $B$ are independent sets then we have a similar idea to the multiplication: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$$

Comment: The analogy with multiplication dates back to [George Boole](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/) and the *algebra of logic* : in his *The Laws of Thought* (1854) where "he used simple letters like $x$ to represent classes; the operation of *multiplication* was defined to be intersection". It is worth to be noted that in this book he considered "*probability theory* as an excellent topic to illustrate the power of his algebra of logic."

Answer (score 2):

In the Boolean notation, $a.b$ denotes conjunction (and, $\land$) and $a+b$ denotes disjunction (or, $\lor$). An overbar $\bar a$ (which can be take for a "minus") denotes negation $\lnot a$.

These parallel set intersection $A\cap B\equiv a\in A\land b\in B$ and set union $A\cup B \equiv a\in A\lor b\in B$. Also set complement $\complement A\equiv \lnot (a\in A)$.

Strange as it may seem, the set difference $A\backslash B\equiv a\in A\land\lnot(b\in B)$ corresponds to the negation of the logical implication $a\in A\nRightarrow b\in B$. There is no reserved notation in Boolean arithmetic (not $a-b$ !), this is just $\overline{a.\bar b}=\bar a+b$.

One also denotes the symmetric difference, $A\Delta B\equiv a\in A\ne b\in B$, corresponding to the exclusive disjunction (xor) $a\oplus b$.

$$\begin{align}
&\complement A&\lnot a&&\bar a&&1-a\\
&A\cap B&a\land b&&a.b&&ab\\
&A\cup B&a\lor b&&a+b&&a+b-ab\\
&A\backslash B&a\nRightarrow b&&&&1-a+b\\
&A\Delta B&a\ne b&&a\oplus b&&a+b-2ab\\
\end{align}$$

The last column indicates how these can be computed using ordinary arithmetic on $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall$ is short for the words "for all" and nothing else.

There is a set algebra where the cut is like multiplication and *exclusive or* is like addition.